# OSX program similar to 'Fences'

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

Is there a Mac program resembling the Windows program 'Fences' (see screenshot below), which allows you to group icons on your screen?

[image]

Comment: Similar question answered on superuser.com:  http://superuser.com/questions/17582/is-there-a-fences-alternative-for-mac-os-x

Comment: @Lars: Thanks for the link - one of the items mentioned, [Drag Thing](http://www.dragthing.com/), looks very similar to Fences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Desktop Groups](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/desktop-groups/id542912361?mt=12) (Which I would describe as the best alternative to fences) is made by the same people who make Desktop Shelves. The product is paid, but the [Lite version of Desktop Groups](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/desktop-groups-lite/id561422617?mt=12) is free.

A good review of its features can found [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/desktop-groups-lite-is-the-best-fences-alternative-for-mac-os-x/) courtesy of Fatima Wahib who reviewed it for Addictive Tips last month:

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure its exactly what you need, but how about something like [DesktopShelves](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/desktopshelves/id446624898?mt=12) (there's also a [free version](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/desktopshelves-lite/id477089918?mt=12))?